# Can I port QtMobility to IMX platform?

Tags: linux, qt, nokia

Any known issues/dependencies in using QtMobility on FreescaleIMX6 Platform. I am planning to run Linux on IMX6 Board.

Comment: iMX6 is very powerful , but it is about 5w when run at full speed . its very hot. If you want to power with battery , Omap4 will be more better.